# Detecting angles in a piechart using OpenCV technique

Tags: python, opencv, contour, angle

I am trying to detect angles in a piechat Image using OpenCV. I detect the lines using `HoughlinesP` and trying to find angles between lines but it is not showing right angle and if there is any straight line (like 180 degree) in pie chart, there will an issue.

I tried another technique using `findContours`. It will give me a boundary area of a piechart, but I stuck there, I don't know what should be next step.

**Edited**
Here is the Image as a sample:

[PieChat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWPtw.jpg)

[This is a result of Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj4Hm.png)

Any help, Any path you given will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the piechart image?

Comment: Kindly Check. I added the images in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thresholding off of the color values of the slices and counting the number of pixels in the slice. I'm converting the pixel count to percentages and then the percentages to angles.

[image]

The output I get is:

[54.4, 18.3, 27.3]

[195.84, 65.88, 98.28]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# get pixel value under mouse
def clicky(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        global h;
        print(h[y][x]);

# load image
img = cv2.imread("pie.jfif");

# resize
scale = 0.5;
h, w = img.shape[:2];
h = int(h*scale);
w = int(w*scale);
img = cv2.resize(img, (w,h));

# hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv);
h = cv2.medianBlur(h, 5);

# find values
cv2.namedWindow("Hue");
cv2.setMouseCallback("Hue", clicky);
while True:
    cv2.imshow("Hue", h);
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break;

# threshold (102, 60, 14)
slices = [];
ranges = [102, 60, 14];
for r in ranges:
    mask = cv2.inRange(h, r-1, r+1);
    slices.append(np.sum(mask == 255));

# convert slices to percentages
percents = [];
total = sum(slices);
for s in slices:
    percent = (s / total) * 100;
    percents.append(round(percent, 1));
print(percents);

# convert to angles
angles = [];
total = 360;
for p in percents:
    angles.append(p * total / 100);
print(angles);
```

Press 'q' on the image to move past the color-finding section of the code.

Comment: you save my day. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way I can get this click event automatically inside a specific area?? sometime I am getting zero value..